# Android. Обновление RecyclerView фрагмента после окончания операции в другом потоке

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, recyclerview, rxjava

Есть 2 фрагмента: первый отвечает за отображение списка товаров, второй показывает детали товара. У второго фрагмента также есть кнопка "Купить", которая уменьшает количество товара в наличии на 1. При нажатии на эту кнопку обновляется запись в БД. Теперь проблема. Мне нужно сымитировать долгую запись в БД, условно 3 секунды. Во втором фрагменте данные обновляются после заданного времени, а в первом фрагменте моментально при переходе от второго. Нужно, чтобы RecyclerView из первого фрагмента обновился после долгой записи в БД в другом потоке, вызванном из второго фрагмента. БД - room, также использую RxJava для упрощения работы с потоками (только начал изучать RxJava)

Первый фрагмент:

```
public class StoreFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = StoreFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CompositeDisposable mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(App.getProductDAO());

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_store_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.shop));
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_store_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        getProducts();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mDisposable.clear();
    }

    private void setAdapter(List<Product> productList){
        StoreFragmentRecyclerAdapter adapter = new StoreFragmentRecyclerAdapter(this.getContext(), new ArrayList<>(productList), false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void getProducts(){
        mDisposable.add(dataAdapter.getProducts()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .toFlowable()
                .flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable)
                .filter(products -> products.getCount() > 0)
                .toList()
                .subscribe(this::setAdapter, throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "Unable to get products", throwable)));
    }
}
```

Второй фрагмент:

```
public class DetailItemFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = DetailItemFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private Product mProduct;
    private CompositeDisposable mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(App.getProductDAO());


    public DetailItemFragment(Product product) {
        this.mProduct = product;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_item, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        TextView nameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_detail_item_text_view_name_good);
        TextView priceTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_detail_item_text_view_price_good);
        TextView countTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_detail_item_text_view_count_good);

        nameTextView.setText(mProduct.getName());
        priceTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f руб.", mProduct.getPrice()));
        countTextView.setText(String.format("%d шт.", mProduct.getCount()));

        Button buyButton = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_detail_item_button_buy);
        buyButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            mProduct.buyProduct();
            mDisposable.add(dataAdapter.update(mProduct)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .delay(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(() -> countTextView.setText(String.format("%d шт.", mProduct.getCount())),
                            throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "Unable to update products", throwable)));
        });
    }
}
```

Как лучше всего реализовать данную задачу? Желательно силами RxJava

Comment: Нужно глянуть куда то в сторону LiveData

Comment: Там у вас нет никакой имитации задержки записи в бд, у вас запись идёт сразу, а задержка на получение результата.

Comment: Да, это я уже понял. Вот я и не могу понять, как сделать эту задержку в записи, а не в получении результата

Comment: У вас задержка сейчас стоит при переходе в UI поток, что бы сделать задержку перед записью переместите .delay(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) перед subscribeOn(). Так же, так как будет задержка и при быстром переходе обратно на 1 фрагмент, если время не истечет, то будет утечка памяти. Если переход будет быстрым(как вы сказали, данные у вас обновляются сразу), то метод загрузит не обновленные данные. Можно реализовать Observable который хранит определенное количество данных, например последний список, а потом подписаться на него или сделать Observable, который при каждом изменении БД автообвлятся

Comment: Если не решили еще данную задачу, отпишитесь

Comment: @AlexGin, да, все еще думаю. Я и хочу понять, как сделать такой Observable - в каком месте и как это реализовывать пока не ясно

Answer (score 0):

Так происходит из-за того, что оператор `delay(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` во втором фрагменте стоит после Observable `dataAdapter.update(mProduct)`, это означает что продукт в БД обновляется почти сразу, а потом происходит задержка 3 секунды прежде чем выполнится `subscribe`. Но в первом фрагменте Observable работает без задержки и обновляет данные сразу же как только они обновились в БД. В вашем случае поможет поставить задержку перед запуском Observable с обновлением, это можно сделать например через `Observable.timer`:

```
mDisposable.add(Observable.timer(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .map(t->dataAdapter.update(mProduct))
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(() -> countTextView.setText(String.format("%d шт.", mProduct.getCount())),
                            throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "Unable to update products", throwable)));
```

Так как `Observable.timer` сразу подписывается на Schedulers.computation(), чтобы поменять в операции с БД шедулер на io нужно перед `map` поставить `observeOn(Schedulers.io())`

Comment: Среда ругается на `() -> countTextView.setText(String.format("%d шт.", mProduct.getCount()). Пишет ошибку "cannot infer functional interface type". Как вылечить?

Comment: В общем, да, так запуск откладывается, но запись в саму БД происходит через раз, причем от чего зависит я не могу уловить

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть в Logcat на предмет стектрейса ошибок (можно отфильтровать по Unable to update products - это текст, который посылается у вас в коде)

Comment: В логи ошибок не выводит